# jQuery - Combine .hide() and .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to define a function to `remove element after x milliseconds`.

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  remove: function(x) {
    this.hide(x);

    //this line won't work
    //setTimeout(function(){ this.remove() }, x);
  }
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").remove(600);
});
```

```css
p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  how are
  <p>you?</p>
</div>
<button>remove</button>
```

After clicking the button, html looks like this:

```
<div>
   <p style="display: none;">Hello</p>
   how are
   <p style="display: none;">you?</p>
</div>
<button>remove</button>
```

My problem is: The line: `setTimeout(function(){ this.remove() }, x);` didn't work. I think the compiler didn't understand what did `this` mean?

Can you give me any idea to call `remove()` function inside `setTimeout`?

Comment: `remove (hidden) element after x milliseconds` Not sure why you want to delay it?

Comment: @A.Wolff I want to add effect `.hide([duration])` before removing the element

Comment: So ya, that's making sense and use complete animation callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the `setTimeout` refers to the window object.

Use complete callback of [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete)

> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

```
this.hide(x, function() {
  this.remove();
});
```

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  remove: function(x) {
    this.hide(x, function() {
      this.remove();
    });
  }
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").remove(600);
});
```

```css
p {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  how are
  <p>you?</p>
</div>
<button>remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, firstly `this` in the `setTimeout()` does not refer to the element which raised the click, but the `window`. You need to store the `this` reference in a variable within the function body. Secondly, inside the `setTimeout` you call `remove()` again, which creates a circular reference which only serves to create a new timeout. You need to change the name of the function so that `remove()` is still valid. Try this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    delayedRemove: function (x) {
        var $el = this;
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $el.remove() 
        }, x);
    }
});

$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").delayedRemove(600);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yLeres7k/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `timeout`, you can remove the element in the done callback of `hide`.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    remove: function (x) {
        this.hide(x, function () {
            this.remove();
        });
    }
});
```